# How to add two ActionListener on the same button to perform Timer.start() / Timer.stop() method

Tags: java

I was trying to make a stopwatch and I was able to do so with the help of some youtube videos and codes I found here. But all those codes had two JButton objects, one to start and the other one to stop the timer. Can anyone help me out to perform both start and stop function from a single button. Thanks in advance.

Below is one of the things I tried that didn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
private Timer t;
private int sec, min, hrs;
static private JPanel p;
private JButton start;
private JLabel l1;

public Test()
{
    p = new JPanel();
    l1 = new JLabel("" + hrs + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
    start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
                {
                    sec++;
                    if (sec == 60)
                    {
                        min++;
                        sec = 0;
                    }
                    if (min == 60)
                    {
                        hrs++;
                        min = 0;
                    }
                    l1.setText("" + hrs + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
                    start.setText("Stop");

                }
            });
            t.start();
            if(start.getText().equals("Stop"))
            {
                start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve)
                    {
                        t.stop();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    p.add(l1);
    p.add(start);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test te = new Test();
    te.add(p);
    te.setSize(240, 360);
    te.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    te.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a class like this:

```
class ToggleButton extends JButton {
    private boolean selected;
    private String otherText;

    public ToggleButton(String text, String otherText) {
        super(text);
        this.otherText = otherText;
        this.setSelected(true);
        this.fixListener();
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    private void fixListener() {
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (isSelected()) {
                    setSelected(false);
                    t.start();
                } else {
                    setSelected(true);
                    t.stop();
                }
                String text = getText();
                setText(otherText);
                otherText = text;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And call it like this: `JButton start = new ToggleButton("Start","Stop");`

This also means that if the timer can also stop and start by another button or method then this button needs to be updated. Which is why `setSelected()` is public.

I am also adding a timer class to help you with your timer.
Initialize it by doing `new Timer(ping);` *(ping is an integer that shows the delay between ticks in milliseconds)*. 
Start it and pause it by using `start()` and `pause()` respectively.

```
public class Timer extends Thread {
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private boolean paused;
    private int ping;

    public Time(int ping){
        this.ping = ping;
        running = false;
        paused = true;
    }

    private void loop(){
        while(running){
            if(paused){
                tick();//check at the end
            }
            delay(ping);
        }
    }

    private void delay(int mil) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mil);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }else{
            paused = false;
        }
    }

    public void pause(){
        paused = true;
    }

    public void reset(){
        thread = null;
        running = false;
        paused = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        paused = false;
        loop();
    }
}
```

Add this method to your Test class

```
public void tick(){
    sec++;
    if (sec >= 60){
        min++;
        sec = sec - 60;
    }
    if (min >= 60){
        hrs++;
        min = min - 60;
    }
}
```

Fixed your Test class, just change it to this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private Timer timer;
    private int sec, min, hrs;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton start;
    private JLabel label1;

    public Test() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel("" + hrs + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
        timer = new Timer(1000);
        start = new ToggleButton("Start", "Stop");
        panel.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(start, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setSize(240, 360);
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void tick() {
        sec++;
        if (sec >= 60) {
            min++;
            sec = sec - 60;
        }
        if (min >= 60) {
            hrs++;
            min = min - 60;
        }
        label1.setText("" + hrs + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
    }

    private class ToggleButton extends JButton {
        private boolean selected;
        private String otherText;

        public ToggleButton(String text, String otherText) {
            super(text);
            this.otherText = otherText;
            this.setSelected(true);
            this.fixListener();
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }

        private void fixListener() {
            addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if (isSelected()) {
                        setSelected(false);
                        timer.start();
                    } else {
                        setSelected(true);
                        timer.pause();
                    }
                    String text = getText();
                    setText(otherText);
                    otherText = text;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class Timer extends Thread {
        private Thread thread;
        private boolean running;
        private boolean paused;
        private int ping;

        public Timer(int ping) {
            this.ping = ping;
            running = false;
            paused = true;
        }

        private void loop() {
            while (running) {
                if (!paused) {
                    tick();
                }
                delay(ping);
            }
        }

        private void delay(int mil) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(mil);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        public void start() {
            if (thread == null) {
                thread = new Thread(this);
                thread.start();
            } else {
                paused = false;
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            paused = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            running = true;
            paused = false;
            loop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for answering so quickly. I tried adding the class and calling the ToggleButton, the text on the button got changes when i click the start button but doesn't stop. Below is how I did

Comment: Oops didn't know that we can't put codes in the comment. Well, I removed the   t.start()   setText("Stop")   from my code and called the Togglebutton while declaration.    start = new ToggleButton("Start", "Stop"); Can you please explain the codes to me furthermore.

Comment: @Ting you do not need to add another actionListener to the button. it is already ready.

Comment: Oh, I got you now. I have removed the ActionListener from test class and added the   algorithms   to calculate in the toggleButton's class but it stops counting after 1.

Comment: @Ting check my answer again. I added a new class called Timer that will help you.

Comment: @Ting  No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a field that represents whether or not the timer is on. In your `ActionListener` you can check the status of this variable when it is called and either stop or start the timer based on it.

```
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve){
        if(timerIsOn)
            t.stop();
        else
            t.start();
        timerIsOn = !timerIsOn; // This will toggle the value of the variable, so if it was false it will now be true and vice versa

     }
});
```

Replace `timerIsOn` with the name of the field you declare and ensure you initialise it with the value `false`.